# How to query multiple vertexes' common tail vertex in titan?

Tags: graph, titan, gremlin

In the graph, there are 3 vertexes A, B, C, they all connect to a vertex D with a edge E. Now I have A B C, how can I query their common tail vertex D with gremlin query?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you might do it - note that I added an E vertex that was not in common with A, B and C:

```
gremlin> g.addV(id,'A').as('a').
......1>   addV(id,'B').as('b').
......2>   addV(id,'C').as('c').
......3>   addV(id,'D').as('d').
......4>   addV(id,'E').as('e').
......5>   addE('knows').from('d').to('a').
......6>   addE('knows').from('d').to('b').
......7>   addE('knows').from('d').to('c').
......8>   addE('knows').from('e').to('a').
......9>   addE('knows').from('e').to('c').iterate()
gremlin> ids = ['A','B','C']
==>A
==>B
==>C
gremlin> g.V(ids).in().
......1>   where(out().id().fold().order().is(eq(ids))).
......2>   dedup()
==>v[D]
```

The `where()` basically traverses back to the head vertex and collects them into a list of identifiers which can then be compared against the original list of identifiers we used to start the traversal. Note that we rely on the identifier `order()` to ensure equality of the lists as:

```
gremlin> ['A','B','C'] == ['A','C','B']
==>false
```